# Name of story with video phones and personal contact is embarrassing

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for the name of a science fiction short story in which characters lack modesty when communicating over video phones but direct contact is excruciatingly embarrassing.

Comment: It's not a short story, and they use hologram-like telepresence instead of video screens, but I immediately thought of the Solarians in Isaac Asimov's novel "The Naked Sun": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Sun

Comment: So, wait - video & other remote interaction is the norm and direct face-to-face contact is awkward? Sounds like real life to me.

Comment: @Omegacron I know right?

Comment: Reminds of the episode "The Haven" from The Outer Limits.

Comment: @Royal is correct.  The story is Naked Sun by Asimov. I remember it well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe [The Machine Stops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops) by E. M. Forster. Published in 1909.

> The story describes a world in which most of the human population has
>   lost the ability to live on the surface of the Earth. Each individual
>   now lives in isolation below ground in a standard 'cell', with all
>   bodily and spiritual needs met by the omnipotent, global Machine.
>   Travel is permitted but unpopular and rarely necessary. **Communication
>   is made via a kind of instant messaging/video conferencing machine
>   called the speaking apparatus**, with which people conduct their only
>   activity, the sharing of ideas and what passes for knowledge. The two
>   main characters, Vashti and her son Kuno, live on opposite sides of
>   the world. Vashti is content with her life, which, like most
>   inhabitants of the world, she spends producing and endlessly
>   discussing secondhand 'ideas'. Kuno, however, is a sensualist and a
>   rebel. He persuades a reluctant Vashti to endure the journey **(and the
>   resultant unwelcome personal interaction)** to his cell.

...
[Full text here.](http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/prajlich/forster.html)
...
...
*Seems someone was looking for a very similar story (perhaps the same one): [Name of the Sci fi book where all human contact is via video link?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17593/name-of-the-sci-fi-book-where-all-human-contact-is-via-video-link)*

Comment: That's the one I thought of too, but "**lack modesty** when communicating over video phones" doesn't seem to fit. "And in the armchair there sits a swaddled lump of flesh--a woman, about five feet high, with a face as white as a fungus." Far from being nude, she is "swaddled".

Comment: @user14111 Lack of modesty does not necessarily mean naked. :D

Comment: Then what interpretation do you put on the OP's words "lack modesty when communicating over video phones"? What sort of modesty does Vashti lack in Forster's story?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Michel Houellebecq's 'The Possibility of an Island'? It has been a while since I read it. It has two narrative threads. The present and the future. In the future the last remaining clones of a man in the present live alone and eschew all physical contact with each other. However they are in relative constant contact through electronic means.