# A story about turning all four walls into TV screens; becoming a totally inert human

Tags: story-identification

I read a story as a kid in the 80's about a person or people who had one full-wall-sized TV screen in their room (I think they lived in a room, not an apartment). They got another one, then one more, and of course by the end had all 4 walls become screens, leading to a very passive existence.

I have no recollection of author or title, but this none-too-subtle premise still holds interest for me. Help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idea of having multiple walls in a single room act as a sort of giant, wraparound television is used in *Fahrenheit 451*, but I doubt it's what you're looking for. The other details don't match up, and it's a novella, not a short story. Since Ray Bradbury has an interest in the idea of a whole room as a big television, a list of his short stories might be a good place to start looking.

Comment: We already have a couple of [questions on E.M Forster's "The Machine Stops"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73989/name-of-story-with-video-phones-and-personal-contact-is-embarrassing), which could be your story.

Answer (score 13):

There's a short story by Keith Laumer titled [The Walls](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57911) which resembles your description.

It starts with a husband telling his wife he knows that she doesn't like the apartment and he's going to do something about it. No, not move them to the country but to install a full wall television. This then graduates to a second, third and fourth wall to her horror.

I don't remember the full story, but I think she has a transcendent moment where she sees through the televisions and can see everyone just watching television in their homes.

I read the story in a collection that had as the following entry a story called [Cocoon](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57896) where people where completely motionless and virtually helpless yet unaware of it because of how the devices overrode their senses.

Comment: "The Walls" and "Cocoon" appear together (but not consecutively) in the collection [*Nine by Laumer*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?195705).